# I'm trying to translate x86-64 assembly code into equivalent C code. How can I get the value contained in %rsp?

Tags: c, assembly, x86

My idea was that a pointer to the most recently initialized local variable would contain the current value of %rsp. Is this correct?

Comment: Where did you get that idea from?

Comment: There's no direct translation of %esp into C. You'll have to explain more about what the code is using %esp for.

Comment: You could try to write something in C and use GDB and some other tool I forget the name of right now to see the assembly and I think check registers? I don't remember 100%. Not sure if this even helps.

Comment: No. Not only is this not correct, this is not even wrong.

Comment: Do you actually need to know the value of %rsp (the stack pointer), or is that something you just think you need? In other words, are you actually asking the right question? What is the real problem? Show some of the assembler and how you ported it to C. Then ask about the problem you have. Perhaps you don't need to know the stack pointer in your C code at all. Often, in assembler, local variables are addressed relative to the stack pointer (or the base pointer, %rbp) and perhaps you only need to know which local variables you must declare and how they are used in C.

Comment: For a better chance of getting a specific answer, I suggest showing us the assembler code you are trying to convert to _C_.

Answer (score 2):

C doesn't have a concept of registers (the nearly obsolete `register` keyword notwithstanding). There is no portable way to read a specific register in C.

The closest you could get is to use some compiler-specific mechanism for inline assembly code, but then you might as well just use assembly language.

A particular compiler will use the `%rsp` register for whatever it chooses (possibly affected by an ABI). And of course a compiler for a different CPU won't use `%rsp` at all.

I suggest you take a step back and decide what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

If your "decompiled" C version of a function still does anything with the stack pointer directly, you did it wrong.  Make up a name for the C variable that the asm is accessing through the stack pointer.

If your C still looks like the asm, you're writing an x86 simulator.